# change reconfiguration gui content during runtime

Tags: ros, c++, parameter-server, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

is there a way to generate the content of the reconfiguration GUI during runtime? For instance a drop down list where it's content is decided after program start.

I know the variables are declared in the .cfg and I need to compile the package in order to get the according header files. But is it possible to assign a created parameter on the parameter server to, for instance a drop down list?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233108/change-reconfiguration-gui-content-during-runtime/) by [chrisb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23915/chrisb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at http://answers.ros.org/question/211686/how-to-set-the-dynamic-reconfigure-min-max-values-programmatically/ , it does appear possible to at least spawn a configure at runtime in python, I haven't tried out adding or removing or altering elements live- the gui might need to be refreshed after each change.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0